# Error document 404 "message" directive not working in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cpanel

I do anything for a few days, .htaccess 404 does not work. I tried hundreds of methods, but I did not get it again
this my httaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

ErrorDocument 404 "test comment"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://spahan.ir/$1 [R=301,L]

       RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.spahan\.ir$
       RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/spahan\.ir\/" [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^spahan.ir [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.spahan.ir/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```